# Do muslims believe that everything that is Allah reveals to Muhammad is in Quran?

Tags: quran

I read a bunch of articles

This

https://www.quora.com/What-is-Islams-stance-on-anal-and-oral-sex

For example, claims that according to Muhammad, Allah prohibits anal sex.

http://wakeup313.blogspot.com/2013/03/allah-has-body-3.html this says that Allah has a body. So Muhammad told one of his buddy about that according to some hadist.

My guess is it's not in quran. If it is, then it wouldn't be "controversial" as the answers to those questions show.

So how come some things that is revealed to Muhammad, such as, "Don't have anal sex" doesn't show up in Quran.

Is Quran incomplete?

Did Allah send messages to Muhammad under 2 categories. Okay, this messages shall be part of quran. This one is not.

Or how?

Comment: It's not duplicate. I know hadith is like gospel. It contains biography of Muhammad. However, are there things that Allah supposedly told Muhammad that's not in Quran? For example, I've heard also that Allah told Muhammad about some battle formation, or that Muhammad is about to be poisoned (it's controversial). Is that part of quran? Who decides what should be in quran or not?

Comment: Your overall question has actually been explained there (Muhammad applied the Qur'an so the sunnah is an extended explanation of the qur'an) if you want an answer for your special cases ask each one of them separately! You should know that the better way to push a re-opening of your question is editing it and showing why it is no duplicate.

Answer (score -1):

Concerning laws and rules you are confusing constitutional law with statute law and ethical law.  The Quran is the Islamic constitution.  It has to be flexible and general since it is for all time.  It is not befitting for a holy book such as the Quran to even mention abominations like anal sex.  Although you might say it is addressed with the prohibition on homosexuality.

It is against nature and serves no biological function.

Comment: not very clear here.